# Have a defined "buffer" for TRUE values, and turn TRUE into FALSE if inside "buffer"

Tags: r

`buffer` means the minimal amount of places **after** `TRUE` where no `TRUE` can live.

data:

```
vec <- as.logical(c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1))

#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

examples for different buffer numbers:

```
buffer = 1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

and

```
buffer = 2
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

and last

```
buffer = 3
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably there is a better way but here is an option, looping through the `TRUE` values of `vec`:

```
changeTRUE <- function(vec, buffer){
                 first_TRUE <- which(vec)[1] # get the first TRUE value index
                 i <- 1 # just so we can move on other TRUE values later
                 while(first_TRUE < length(vec)){ # while there are some TRUE
                   vec[(first_TRUE+1):min((first_TRUE+buffer), length(vec))] <- FALSE # put FALSE after the TRUE value according to buffer value (but not further than the end of vec)
                   i <- i+1 # to go to next TRUE
                   first_TRUE <- which(vec)[i] # get next TRUE index...
                 }
                 return(vec)
             }

changeTRUE(vec, 1)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
changeTRUE(vec, 2)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
changeTRUE(vec, 3)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: very good. I made a version without index `i` not sure if it's faster. (see my edit)

Answer (score 2):

Variant of @Cath answer using recursive function, I don't expect it to be quicker than the raw wile loop, that's for the sake of educational purpose (will break on large vectors, r will consider an infinite recursion at some point):

```
cT2 <- function(vec, buffer, index = 1) {
  if (!is.na(first_TRUE <- which(vec)[index])) {
    vec[(first_TRUE+1):min((first_TRUE+buffer), length(vec))] <- FALSE
    vec <- cT2(vec,buffer, index+1)
  }
  vec
}
```

Out of curiosity a small benchmark of all solutions so far (my system crash with bigger vector, I didn't dig into which function made it crash, I suspect mine):

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
vec <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),1e4,TRUE)
microbenchmark(changeTRUE(vec,3),cT2(vec,3),changeTRUE2(vec,3),times=10)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
  changeTRUE(vec, 3)  64.58125  65.36158  67.4990  66.26165  67.70284  73.94888    10
         cT2(vec, 3)  75.84567  81.25721 111.0525 122.09651 124.63022 134.54896    10
 changeTRUE2(vec, 3) 179.11084 185.51882 201.1573 193.79123 217.79790 234.92004    10
```

Answer (score 1):

All creds go to @Cath's solution

A version without `i<-`

```
changeTRUE2 <- function(vec, buffer){
    first_TRUE <- which(vec)[1]
        while(first_TRUE < length(vec)){
        vec[(first_TRUE+1):min((first_TRUE+buffer), length(vec))] <- FALSE
        first_TRUE <- which(c(rep(FALSE,first_TRUE),vec[-(1:first_TRUE)]))[1]
    }
    return(vec)
}

changeTRUE(vec, 1)
changeTRUE2(vec, 1)
changeTRUE(vec, 2)
changeTRUE2(vec, 2)
changeTRUE(vec, 3)
changeTRUE2(vec, 3)
```

---

Not sure whether thats any faster.